# Is there a way to define a custom query on a model (Sequelize)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a model of the below table using sequelize.

```
CREATE TABLE MoneyTransaction(
  id serial,
  incre text generated always as (lpad(id::text, 8, '0')) stored,
  name text
);
```

Edit: what I tried so far with setters, However I am not familiar with getters and setters

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const MoneyTransaction = sequelize.define(
    'MoneyTransaction',
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      incre: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        async set() {
          this.setDataValue('incre', await sequelize.query("generated always as (lpad(id::text, 8, '0')) stored"));
        },
      },
     
      },
    },
    {}
  );

  return MoneyTransaction;
};
```

IS it possible please? how to

Comment: AFAIK, sequelize does not support generated columns.  if you only need this in the context of a sequelize ORM, you could use a [Virtual field](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html). Some people have simulated a generated column with [universal hooks](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#global---universal-hooks)

Comment: According to the updated info in the answer would you please, provide some code of how it would look like @KenOn10